# taking unset() and rewriting this function in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a PHP function on my website as follows:

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$x = $url;
$parsed = parse_url($x);
$query = $parsed['query'];
parse_str($query, $params);
unset($params['page']);
$string = http_build_query($params);
```

which removes the 'page' parameter from the current URL.

What I need to do now however is write the same function but in javascript, to use in an onclick. I have searched and come up with the following solution:

```
$('#localtab').click(function() {
     return location.href=location.href.replace(/&?page=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "");
});
```

this is working but as this is the first ever time I've coded regex, am I doing this page reload in the best possible way? I don't wanna risk knocking off any other parameters, although there are none others containing the phrase 'page'.

For example, is it best to check first if the page parameter is present in the URL (because sometimes it isn't in fact) and how would I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: How your input looks like and what's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj ?use_url=on&zipcode=Axminster%2C+Devon+EX13+5RZ&radius=0&seasoning=1&slider-value1=0&slider-value2=70&resultbar=10&sortbar=distance&lat=50.776434&lng=-2.981042&swlat=50.777353&swlng=-2.981451&nelat=50.780051&nelng=-2.974995&outcode=EX13&page=1#tabs1-nat

Comment: though as I mentioned the &page= is not always present. I could always include php in the jquery `if(isset($_GET['page'])) { `

Comment: If you’re not sure whether your regex is sufficient or safe: Getting GET parameters from the URL in JS has been discussed a couple of times already; so you could take one of those existing solutions to get all parameters as an array or object, remove the unwanted one, and then re-build the query string from the remaining values.

Comment: @CBroe i've been looking but obviously in the wrong place, but if you say it can be done with javascript and without regex then i'll search more and update with my solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is RegExp is supposed to be used for patterns. And it will only work if the pattern matches. No you don't need to check if `page` exists before clearing it.